# Memorize and jump to different location in a very long Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm working on a very long document in Word 2013.

I have to copy/paste a lot of elements from a position to another one. So I want to quick memorize the "target" position, go the position where the elements to copy are then return to the "target" position.

What is the fastest way to do that ? Is it mandatory to use named bookmarks ?

Comment: Are you trying to create a [table of contents](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/285059/how-to-create-a-table-of-contents-by-marking-text-in-word)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is by simply making a duplicate instance of word from your current document.

You can do this by *View* > *New Window*

In menu *View* you can now select, *Side by side* which will show both windows neatly next to eachother.

On the left side, scroll to where you have the text that you want to move, and on the right side, scroll to where you want to move the text to.

You can now Cut and Paste the text easily from one window to the other and as you make a change on either side of the document, both views get updated.

Comment: indeed, I haven't thinking to this option... But is there another way to achieve this thing ?

Comment: I don't think there is a better option.